# Is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, dll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0581.jpg)

this is 1 project and this project I create .dll and that using another project but there error coming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9jpU.jpg)

enter image description here this is 1 project and this project I create .dll and that using another project but there error coming

In this project, I creating instance here and the previous project I remove static also and next image I will show error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGqOh.jpg)

Error 1 'TS_COM.Bus_D.Device1' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' D:\TOOLS\TestFrameWork\COM_SERVER -Internal - sBus - Copy\TS_COM\sBusDriver.cs 38 13 TS_COM

Error 2 'TS_COM.Bus_D.Device2' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' D:\TOOLS\TestFrameWork\COM_SERVER -Internal - sBus - Copy\TS_COM\sBusDriver.cs 39 13 TS_COM

I try both ways but no one works

Comment: Please don´t post code as images. Instead copy the code directly into the question.

Comment: What is that code (`Device1.sCANBaudRate_En_t sBuad_CH1;`) supposed to do? Do you want to declare a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have `Device1.sCANBaudRate_En_t sBuad_CH1;`. For compiler this means that you are declaring variable `sBuad_CH1` of type `Device1.sCANBaudRate_En_t`. But, it is not a type, it is variable too (field, to be precise).
That's explanation of the error message. For the solution, it depends what you actually wanted to accomplish.

Edit (based on comment):
`Device1` is of type `sBus` and if `sCANBaudRate_En_t` is enum, it is either defined under class `sBus` in which case your line should be `sBus.sCANBaudRate_En_t sBuad_CH1`, or it is property/field of `sBus` class. In that case find that property/field and see it's type. It should be something like `public YourEnumType sCANBaudRate_En_t {get;set;}`. Then, your line should be `YourEnumType sBuad_CH1`.

Comment: "sCANBaudRate_En_t" this is enum is a part of .dll  and I want to create an instance of that enum in my project

Comment: Hello Sir, you understand my question?